# Minimizing the sum of the $4^\text{th}$ power of a matrix entries.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Consider a real $n\times n$ matrix $X$. Suppose I would like to minimize the sum of the squares of its entries as a penalty term in some convex minimization. I can write the term using the Frobenius norm $\operatorname{Tr}(X^T X)$ and then take the gradient w.r.t. $X$.

What if instead I want to minimize the sum of the $4^\text{th}$ power of the matrix entries?
Is there a way I can write the penalty term in a compact form? (such that I can easily take the gradient w.r.t. $X$)

Thanks a lot.

Fabio

Comment: I don't think there's a nice way.  You'll have to use something like a [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

Comment: Why would you want to minimize $4$th powers. Looks weird. What's the underlying problem ?

Comment: Sure, it may be weird, but there's nothing fundamentally wrong with it. The gradient is easy, because it is computed elementwise: the derivative with respect to $X_{ij}$ is just $4X_{ij}^3$. In fact, this is simple enough that I can't help think we're missing something. What's so difficult about $f(X)=\sum_{i,j} X_{ij}^4$?